# Cannot get sound file (WAV) to play on RPi3 using latest Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

We want to play a WAV file somewhere in my headless UWP **background** application on ***Windows 10 IoT Core***. For this i have followed the Microsoft docs and used the following method:

```
var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/startup.wav"));
mediaPlayer.Play();
```

I have copied the WAV file (startup.wav) to the Assets folder in Visual Studio, set it to always copy to output and compiled the UWP application. No matter how i try i don't get any sound output. I tried 2 Raspberry PI's (both version 3) and connected my pc speakers to the output jack of the Raspberry.

I also granted the application the correct permissions in the package.appxmanifest:

```
<uap3:Capability Name="backgroundMediaPlayback"/>
```

If i go to the device portal i see on the right side the default Raspberry pi 2 audio with slidebar active. Which i guess is a sign drivers are correct.

What can i do to play a simple wav file in my headless **background** UWP application? Maybe i am doing something wrong, hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Hi Rodney Koolman, if the answer help you solved the issue you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If not please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. When i tried a third raspberry it works, no idea why but maybe i have bad luck and two head-jack ports are broken :).

Thanks for all your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

> I have copied the WAV file (startup.wav) to the Assets folder in Visual Studio

Like this right?

[image]

It is not the right place. You can check the IsOpen property of mediaPlayer.Source when debugging, it will be false.

[image]

You need put the audio file in appx folder, for me, it is like this: PlayAudioBackground\bin\ARM\Debug\AppX\Assets.

[image]

You can have a try.

Reference: "[URI schemes - ms-appx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes#ms-appx-and-ms-appx-web)" "[UWP sample - Background media playback sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundMediaPlayback)"

**Update:**

For background application the assets folder is not included in project by default. If you want to use this folder to add the audio file you can right click on the assets folder from solution explorer and select "Include In Project". And then set the audio file property "Build Action - Content" and "Copy to output directory - Copy Always".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Rita, thanks for your suggestion. However when i put the file in the Assests in Visual Studio i set the property "Copy to output directory - Copy Always" below the solution explorer. When i debug it locally on my system it works and plays the sound. But on my Raspberry's with Windows 10 IoT core it doens't.

Comment: @RodneyKoolman Are you using [background application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/backgroundapplications)? It can't be running on your system x86/x64.

Comment: Yes i am using background application. I cannot run it on my desktop, but for testing i just deployed the script to a normal application, checked background capability and minimized the application, sound is working. The same script produces no sound on my RPi3 with Windows 10 IoT Core.

I forgot to mention. I indeed have set the Assets folder to be included in the project and have set the file build action to content and the copy to output directory to Copy always. As soon as i deploy the appxbundle to Windows 10 IoT Core, the application runs fine but their is no sound.

Comment: @RodneyKoolman Check the audio file and audio device. Detailed information is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4555a195-4a61-478d-b8e2-431f6b1b96c3/cannot-get-sound-file-wav-to-play-on-rpi3-using-latest-windows-10-iot-core?forum=WindowsIoT#9f878701-1c64-4a24-a923-f65f9c0a075b).